# Qt. Is connection name valuable to connect to the MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, qt, qtsql

Is connection name valuable to connect to the MySQL server?

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "conectionName");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not, If you don't provide then a default name will be given but you can use that name to get that connection some where else.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("connectionName");
```

Here's what documentation says.

> If connectionName is not specified, the new connection becomes the
>   default connection for the application, and subsequent calls to
>   database() without the connection name argument will return the
>   default connection. If a connectionName is provided here, use
>   database(connectionName) to retrieve the connection.

So if you don't provide any name, then whenever the below will return you that connection.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database();
```